# auto focus on Android with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android

I am writing an app using OpenCV. I have used the standard way to use the camera with OpenCV.

```
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_camera);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.show_camera_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
```

The problem is that it seems to work great on my own phones, but not on others of the same model and same android version. I can't test/debug on those myself, since they are in another country. It's a very strange and frustrating problem!

I want to eliminate focus being the issue, so I want to implement auto-focus.

I have spent several days digging through many tutorials and examples of how to add auto-focus. For instance one tutorial (https://www.thecodecity.com/2016/08/focus-modes-opencv-javacameraview-android.html) made me write my own subclass of JavaCameraView. In the example it was

```
public class MyCameraView extends JavaCameraView {
    public MyCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
public void setFocusMode(Context item, int type) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    .......
    mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
    mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
        }
    });
```

The way the tutorial is written actually causes the app to crash... but I rewrote parts to make it run.

I use MACRO mode.  The tutorial worked after my bug fix, but it only focuses ONCE, then holds that focus constant. My app needs the auto-focus to CONTINUE.

I moved the rows after "....." into a method and a call to the same method again within the callback. It seems to work but is it a good way to do it? Any risk of memory leaks? Other negative side-effects?

It works but resets the autofocus too often. I would like to have some pause of 500ms or whatever in between each reset. (Adding `Thread.sleep()` is not a good way.) How can I do that?

Do you know an actual working example of excellent auto-focus code for OpenCV?